# Problems with WIFI, Intel 7260

Tags: networking, wireless

So, I'm on 15.04.  I tried 14.04, but also with no luck. I also tried the latest version of Linux Mint. I've got an Intel wireless 7260 rev 6b in this laptop, and although it finds networks, it just tries to connect forever and times out.

I've tried different versions of firmware, but to no avail.  Also, the wireless button light is just on all the time.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu just released an update for the firmware from Intel:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1453935

Maybe this will solve your problems.